# Suggestions for adding Advanced Search features to a block (using the dashboard)?

Tags: blocks, search, dashboard

Is it possible to do the following:

1. Add a Search box to a block through the [dashboard](https://www.drupal.org/project/dashboard)?
2. Have an Advanced Search on multiple fields in that block?
3. Have the results of the search open in a new page?

I understand that there are options to do this with code, but my client would like to manipulate as many areas as possible through the [dashboard](https://www.drupal.org/project/dashboard).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Search form is itself a block; you should add this box to a region. Let the client configure blocks; they can move the block from admin/structure/block.

> [image: screenshot]